# PSEXEC for get ComputerName in remote Server

Tags: remote-access, psexec

I have Windows 7 machine named MY_MACHINE.
I want connect to Windows Server 2012 named REMOTE_SERVER.
I use psexec 2.11 version.

When I test, I cannot get the OK result that is Computer Name = REMOTE_SERVER

First test:

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /c echo %%computename%%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


%%computename%%
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

Second test:

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /c echo %computename%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


%computename%
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

Third test:

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /c echo %%computername%%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


%MY_MACHINE%
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

4º test:

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c "echo %%computername%%"

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


%MY_MACHINE%
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

5º test:

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c "echo ^%computername^%"

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


%computername%
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

Any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using ^%computername^% without quotes "

```
C:\Tests\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local -u OTHERDOMAIN\ONE_USER
 -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


REMOTE_SERVER
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHERDOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```